# Pythonic way to change range expression into a list

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic way to convert typical string range expressions (like specifying *page range* to *printer*) as

```
'1-4,6'
'3,5-8,12-14'
```

into lists

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
[3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14]
```

This is meant as a brain teaser, I know how to do it in a corny way using string operations and loops.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I know how to do it with lots if `if`s, `split`s and similar.  I just want to know if there is any "pythonic" way to do it.

Comment: String range expression is always `'int-int,int'`  ?

Comment: @WAKR No, you never know where is dash and where is comma.  Just like when you specify page range to printer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following function:

```
def dashrange(s):
    if "-" in s:
        a, b = map(int, s.split("-"))
        return range(a, b + 1)
    return [int(s)]

def range_to_list(s):
    return [j for i in s.split(",") for j in dashrange(i)]
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: function is too complex

Comment: @Faran2007 I tried to simplify the function, see edit

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

range_expr = '1-4,6,9-11'

ranges = []
for r in re.finditer(r'\d+(?:-\d+)?(?=(,|\Z))', range_expr):
    if '-' in r.group(0):
        l = list(map(int, r.group(0).split('-')))
        l[1] += 1
        ranges.extend(list(range(*l)))
    else:
        ranges.append(int(r.group(0)))

print(ranges)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11]
```

**To validate the range and allow white space:**

You can initially test the supplied range for validity using:

```
re.match(r'(\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:(,|\Z)))+$', range_expr)
```

If you want to allow white space:

```
re.match(r'(\s*\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?(?:(\s*,\s*|\s*\Z)))+$', range_expr)
- and -
for r in re.finditer(r'\s*\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?(?=(\s*,\s*|\s*\Z))', range_expr):
```

Answer (score 1):

This has some similarities to @rassar's answer, but writing this as a generator let's us use `yield from` to save us from an extra loop.

The downside to this is you will have to convert the output to a list if you really need a list.

If this is just a brain teaser then I like my answer even more.

```py
def string_range(string):
    for r in string.split(','):
        try:
            yield int(r)
        except ValueError:
            x, y = map(int, r.split('-'))
            yield from range(x, y + 1)

>>> list(string_range('3,5-8,12-14'))
[3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do this

l=list(range(1,5))+[6]

Comment: I am sorry, it was meant that you start with a string.

Answer (score 0):

From your problem, you need to use the `range` function. Use my function

```
def string_to_list(string):
    expr  = string.split(',')[0].replace(' ', '')
    expr1 = expr.split('-')[0]
    expr2 = expr.split('-')[1] 
    last  = string.split(',')[1].replace(' ', '')
    return list(range(int(expr1), int(expr2)+1)) + [int(last)]
```

There's no `built-in` function from your problem, you need to make one, for example
`string_to_list("1-4, 6")` will return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]`